# Getting "size mismatch" when using apt-get on multiple packages

Tags: apt

I'm having trouble getting several packages downloaded using apt-get. So far, I've run into this with 'opencv' and 'gstreamer'. With opencv, it will fetch a number of files then return with the error below. I've tried several different mirrors and they all error on the same file(s).

```
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe libopencvvideo2.3 i386 2.3.1-7 [106 kB]
Get:2 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe libopencv-video-dev i386 2.3.1-7 [129 kB]
Fetched 2,225 B in 0s (11.8 kB/s)        
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/opencv/libopencv-video2.3_2.3.1-7_i386.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/opencv/libopencv-video-dev_2.3.1-7_i386.deb  Size mismatch
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I ran 'apt-cache show libopencv-video*' and got:

```
Package: libopencv-video2.3
Priority: optional
Section: universe/libs
Installed-Size: 277
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Science Team <debian-science-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: i386
Source: opencv
Version: 2.3.1-7
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libopencv-core2.3, libopencv-imgproc2.3 (= 2.3.1-7), libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1)
Filename: pool/universe/o/opencv/libopencv-video2.3_2.3.1-7_i386.deb
Size: 105756
MD5sum: b38c0f11f3856d62168b730522a9691b
SHA1: d45cd609ea497ae72858e0f5914134e124261f22
SHA256: 85e72311ede84efbdd17781cdb04f79818a28968c63f407df6c56efe7da5525e
Description-en: computer vision Video analysis library
```

When i compare the filesize reported (105756) it does not match the size of the 'deb' package when I pull it down with wget.

Any suggestions as to solving this problem short of using wget on each of the failed files and installing them manually?

Comment: It is 105756 Bytes where 106 is kB, hence 105.756 kB is 106 kB when rounded. Which is approximately same.

Comment: right but the filesize of the file (same exact file) that i download using wget is 103kB. seems like the descriptor isn't being updated to match the files?

Comment: The downloaded size seems to change a bit few or hundred KB's ( + or - ) depending on size when downloaded onto Local storage. I had always thought it was for CRC or FEC , but then got confused about the BASE in which bits are stored . If it is so , then i am not sure , probably someone will answer .

Comment: I'm wondering if they are corrupt packages. should i not be able to download (wget, etc) then install using "dpkg -i <package>" on ubuntu? If so, i'm getting this:

Comment: oot@ubuntu:/home/sysadmin# dpkg -i libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev_0.10.36-1ubuntu0.1_i386.deb
dpkg-deb: error: `libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev_0.10.36-1ubuntu0.1_i386.deb' is not a debian format archive
dpkg: error processing libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev_0.10.36-1ubuntu0.1_i386.deb (--install):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev_0.10.36-1ubuntu0.1_i386.deb

Answer (score 19):

It turns out that there is not a problem with apt-get but my company. There is an internet policy that blocks all keywords with 'video' in the url. I discovered this by viewing the contents of the `libopencv-video2.3_2.3.1-7_i386.deb` in `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial`. It contained html from the web filter giving me a notice that I'm in violation of my internet blah blah blah.

Who would have known that their lead research engineer would have had a policy applied so trivial as this?

Lesson learned: ask your IT dept to give a block of addresses that are exempt from stupid policies and charge them back for the time wasted by me and those trying to help...

Comment: Le sigh. Gotta love IT people.

Comment: Proxies/firewalls that return spurious HTML with a 200 OK instead of just blocking the connection are the WORST. :(

Comment: Thanks, @Chris !  Huge help.  Now I can stop wondering what the hell was going on.

Comment: As a beginner, I am very curious about how you got to that solution (looking in `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial`). Was it somewhere in the apt-get manual page? Did you find someone else who had the problem? Something else? I'd really like to get better at solving problems without Google when possible.

Comment: @mathguy54 I got the same error as the OP. I tried to visit the link (using browser or `wget`) and the received file was very small. It turns out to be `html` with message "the url is blocked"

Comment: Gah, my Gryphon router just did this. >:( Thanks for the tip on what to look for.

Answer (score 4):

I had a lot of these problems and I always managed to fix them.

For example:

```
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/opencv/libopencv-video-dev_2.3.1-7_i386.deb
```

In this case I would fetch the package manually from the main server like:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/opencv/libopencv-video-dev_2.3.1-7_i386.deb
```

Notice I removed the us-east stuff.

then just run:

```
sudo dpkg -i libopencv-video-dev_2.3.1-7_i386.deb
```

to install the package.

Then just run the original command you were trying

Comment: Why does apt choke? What are the ramifications of downloading and installing the package that apt choked on?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed size mismatch problem when trying to upgrade owncloud.
Problem was wrong ppa url.

My repo was for xubuntu:

```
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/xUbuntu_15.04/Release
```

Changed to proper ubuntu:

```
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_15.10/Release
```

**Summary:** Make sure you have properly setup ppa's urls for your distribution and flavor of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have experienced this same problem. In my case it was a problem entirely of my own making. I was building new packages for an internal package server and just replacing a package on the server each time without incrementing version numbers ( only me pulling the files ).

**My investigations** went as follows...

- run the `apt-cache show` command - confirm the filesize
- pull with file by hand - confirm that it in fact a missmatch.
- manually check the filesize on the package server it matched the `apt-cache` output

The resulting steps lead me to conclude that my pull of the .deb had been cached.. by our proxy server ( running in transparent mode ). I confirmed that by looking at the proxy logs and it was indeed showing the cache "HIT"

**The solution?**
run the `wget` command again but force the proxy to refresh

```
wget http://packages.example.com/pool/contrib/.../packagename.deb --no-cache
```

that was enough to get the proxy to refresh the file at which point `apt-get` worked normally.

Obviously its bad form to replace a package without bumping the version number but its another possible cause of this issue.